# HTML TreeView Expand rows

Tags: html, knockout.js, tree, treeview, devextreme

I am using knockout and dxTreeView, I have Tree View and HTML table, I want when clicking on a row in the table expand tree view and focus based on the same id in the table and the tree view.
if that impossible  I want to make treeview by html and knockout without devextreme

```
 here is my code
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLVPbb

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using a table for listing clubs. You can simply have an unordered list of clubs and a nested list of all the details.

```
<ul id="myTreeView">
    <li>
        <span>Clubs</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="expandable">CO Harrach</span>
                        <ul class="non-expandable">
                            <li>Address: Asia</li>
                            <li>Open: 24x7</li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="expandable">Zamalek</span>
                        <ul class="non-expandable">
                            <li>Address: Australia</li>
                            <li>Open: 5 days</li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<style>
 #myTreeView {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#myTreeView ul {
list-style-type:none;
}
#myTreeView {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.expandable {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}
.expandable::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
.expanded::before {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */'
  transform: rotate(90deg);  
}
.non-expandable {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
</style>


<script>
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("expandable");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".non-expandable").classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("expanded");
  });
}
</script>
```

I have just created a sample tree view [here](https://codepen.io/ankur-sachdeva/pen/ExxjoPj).

Also, you can read my full article [here](https://blogs.hanumanteysoftwaresolutions.com/html/html-list-everything-you-need-to-know/).